# How to use Haxe "package" declarations?

Tags: haxe

Why **package** declarations like in below two files couses compiler errors, and how to achieve having my declared package on both files (with **Main** included)?

File **Main.hx**

```
package foo;
class Main {
    function new() {
        var x:A = new A();
    }

    static function main() {
        var main = new Main();
    }
}
```

File **A.hx**

```
package foo;
class A {
    public function new() {
        trace('Hi.');   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try structuring your project like this:

```
[project root]
    /source
        /foo
            Main.hx
            A.hx
```

Then call Haxe with these arguments, with `[project root]` as the current working directory:

```
haxe -cp source --interp -main foo.Main
```

The name of `source` doesn't really matter, it could be `src` or `Source`, but the directory the `.hx` files are placed in needs to match their package (`foo`).